# Command to return library (not work) name of a path in modelsim

Tags: tcl, vhdl, modelsim

I want to find a way to return the name of a library of a certain path in a VHDL Design in Modelsim.

Given a VHDL Design with a path like "/mega_tb/D0". This is compiled in a library that is NOT 'work', say "libnwork".
I can of course take a look in my 'do' file to get the correct lib name. Or I can search in ModelSim's Library tab. But I want to have or create a modelsim command which I can later use in a Tcl script, to get the correct library name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te only way I've found is to use the command

```
write report -tcl
```

This prints a long list where I have search for the lib names with regexps.
Something like

```
set data [ write report -tcl]
foreach_regexp { _ type lib entity} $data{
  if {$type == "Entity" && $entity == [entity_of_path /mega_tb/D0] } {
     ....
  }
}
```

Where I of course had to define my "foreach_regexp" procedure and my "entity_of_path" procedure. I then can use something like regsub to extract the library name.

I am still looking for a better and easier way.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to find something in a Tcl script file – which is all a Modelsim “do” file is — is to evaluate it. Tcl's *very* good at that. Of course, you don't want to have the commands do all the conventional things. Instead, we'll evaluate in a context where we can make everything do nothing except for the command that produces the information we want:

```tcl
# Set up our evaluation context, 'worker'
interp create worker -safe
interp eval worker {proc unknown args {}};   # Our do-nothing handler
interp alias worker theInterestingCommand {} ourHandler
proc ourHandler args {
    puts "We were called with: $args"
}

# Parse the file!
set f [open /the/file.tcl]
interp eval worker [read $f]

# Clean up
close $f
interp delete worker
```

Now you just have to make `theInterestingCommand` have the right name and extract the interesting information from the arguments. Which should be relatively easy…

Comment: Thank you, it's really an interesting and clever thing. The problem is that this only works if a tcl file was used to instantiate the design. What would I do if there are only the .vhd files? I still wonder why there is no command in modelsim for that.